# Mobius Function over Euler Totient Function

Tags: totient-function, mobius-function

The question is to prove:

$\sum_{\phi(n)=k}\mu(n) = 0$

where $\phi(n)$ is the Euler totient function and $\mu(n)$ is the Mobius function.

I have tried various approaches but nothing seems to be working. I am not sure but someone recommended using the fact that
$\sum_{d|n}\mu(d)*n/d = \phi(n)$

Comment: Hint: Throw away all addends for which $\mu\left(n\right) = 0$. Among the remaining addends, those for which $n$ is odd are in bijection with those for which $n$ is even. (The bijection sends $n$ to $2n$.) Thus, all the addends cancel.